# How to access the production version of MyWorld Standard offered to support digital identity network built with Platform of trust tools?

Tags: api, platform, platform-of-trust, ontology-network

I have experimented with MyWorld Standard in sandbox environment using as guidance this guide https://developer.oftrust.net/cases/myworld-standard-app/

How can I access production version for this application? Is it available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have account in https://world.oftrust.net/ This is the production environment for creating accounts.
You can access production version of MyWorld Standard here https://myworld.valaa.com/